# Gated Residual and Variable Selection Networks for regression

Tags: tensorflow, keras, feature-selection, deep-residual-networks

I came across [this Keras tutorial](https://keras.io/examples/structured_data/classification_with_grn_and_vsn/) which is for a classification problem, but I'm trying to apply it to a regression one. Does anyone know why they change the dimension of the features? Has anybody used this for regression at all?

Also any link to a related tutorial would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add details of your Questions. Add reproducible code.